# Data type to save a table

Tags: java, python

I want to save a table contain records with some attribute, 
for example

```
Name gender Age 
----------------
Josh Male   22
```

so I can easily access all records and change the attribute,
what is the easiest way to save this data ? ,
in C++ I use double vector.
if you have solution in python or java please tell me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends entirely on how you want to access it.  If you just want access to it in the current running program then following the vector you can do

```
data = []
keys = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age']
persons = (("Josh", "Male", 22), )
for person in persons:
    data.append(dict(zip(keys, person)))
```

Then you can access it as such:

```
>>> data[0]
{'Name': 'Josh', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': 22}
>>> data[0]['Name']
Josh
```

Or even better

```
from collections import namedtuple
n = namedtuple('Person', ('name', 'gender', 'age'))
persons = (("Josh", "Male", 22), )
for person in persons:
    data.append(Person(person))
```

Then you can do

```
>>> p = data[0]
>>> p.name
Josh
```

However, you can't modify a tuple, so you'd have to create a new person and store that person in place of the old person.
If you want to have more control over how you access data (e.g. database style queries, more advanced/easier filtering), might be worth looking into models and querysets: e.g. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/ .

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `dictionary` as follows:

```
attributes = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age']
values = ['Josh', 'Male', 22]

>>> my_dict = dict(zip(attributes,values))
>>> print my_dict
{'Name': 'Josh', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': 22}
```

If you are going to have more values, you can do this instead:

```
values = [['Josh','Helen'], ['Male','Female'], [22,"I'd rather not tell"]]
>>> my_dict = dict(zip(attributes,values))
>>> print my_dict
{'Name': ['Josh','Helen'], 'Gender': ['Male','Female'], 'Age': [22,"I'd rather not tell"]}

>>> print my_dict['Name']
['Josh','Helen']

>>> print my_dict['Gender'][1]
Female
```